Configuring audio on PopOS virtual machine using Hyper -V on windows 11 host machine
I need help to get audio working on PopOS virtual machine that I have installed on my windows 11 home edition os using Hyper -v.
I used the pop-os_22.04_amd64_nvidia_41 iso for the install of virtual machine. When i try to play any videos on it there is no audio. In sound section of settings it only shows dummy audio. No actual audio device is available.
I have seen few solutions online for ubuntu and none of them are very clear and there's no clear documentation for this. Some of the solutions use pulseaudio but PopOS depends on pipwire-pulse. 
https://www.elevenforum.com/t/how-to-get-sound-on-ubuntu-in-hyper-v.801/ 
https://scientificprogrammer.net/2024/01/23/getting-audio-working-on-ubuntu-vm-on-hyper-v/ 
https://www.elevenforum.com/t/how-to-get-sound-on-ubuntu-in-hyper-v.801/
edit
found another article talking about audio redirection with xrdp and pipwire instead of pulseaudio.
https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=19103

@John It is a generation 2 vm that I have installed. Everything works fine besides the audio problem. The peformance is a lot better compared to what I got on virtualbox. The thing I heard a lot of people say hyper -v isn't really meant to have audio support out of the box. But I have seen people configuring it through ffmpeg or xrdp whicih I don't really know what that means. I know it can be done I just don't have enough knowledge about this to figure it out by myself honestly.

It's not that hard but it takes time and work to set it up. That said, all I know about it was from the time every mainstream distro relied on pulsaudio. With the move towards pipewire I'm as clueless as you.

Doesn't Hyper-V VM provides audio support only with the RDP-ish "enhanced session"? Probably need this?

@TomYan I installed that but it doesn't really change anything. Its def a step forward but I don't really know enough about this thing to figure it out by myself. At least I now know xrdp uses pulseaudio-module-xrdp to redirect audio on other systems and on pop os it has to be the pipwire-module-xrdp. I still don't know how to really configure xrdp and it's dependencies to make it really work. Honestly all of this is because popos shifted from pulseaudio to pipwire otherwise there were already solutions. I haven't seen a single solution for popos on whole internet.

PoP_OS is Ubuntu based and was also Ubuntu that changed to pipewire some time ago. Search for Ubuntu instead and most of what you'll find is applicable to yours.

All of this assumes that your distro comes with pipewire instead of pulseaudio. If not, then there are a lot of tutorials on the web for distros with pulseaudio.
The main components are having pipewire-module-xrdp installed and also having xrdp installed with all it's dependencies.
Then you have to boot into your VM in enhanced session mode by executing few commands on powershell. You can find articles on how to do that on the web easily. After that it should work. I will try to expand on this answer later.

Oh sorry my bad. Still pretty new to using these forums but i will be more diligent from next time.
